# Class Group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-47})$

Tags: number-theory

Calculate the group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-47})$.

I have this: The Minkowski bound is $4,36$ approximately.

Thanks!

Comment: @Potato, i need to use the Minkowski bound!

Comment: Thought I deleted that...Anyway, is there any $\mathbb Q (\sqrt {-n})$ for which you do know how to find the class group?

Comment: Just for the record, this is isomorphic to the group of positive binary quadratic forms of discriminant $-47$ under Gauss composition, which is pretty easy.

Comment: @P.M.O. I give an elementary approach below.

Comment: By the way, if people want to check their answers against tables of imaginary quadratic fields of small class number, see e.g. here: http://www.numbertheory.org/classnos/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shown that every ideal class contains an integral ideal with norm at most $4$.

Recall how primes split in quadratic fields. Because $-47$ is $1$ mod $8$, we have

$$(2)=\left(2, \frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2}\right)\left(2, \frac{1-\sqrt{-47}}{2}\right).$$

Because $-47$ is $1$ mod $3$, we have

$$(3)=(3,1-\sqrt{-47})(3,1+\sqrt{-47}).$$

It is easy to see that these are all non-principal. Note that the norm of $1+\sqrt{-47}$ is $48=2^4\cdot 3$. Note that $(3,1+\sqrt{-47})$ divides $(1+\sqrt{-47})$, with the rest of the factors being one of the two factors of $2$ above.

This shows that we only need the prime factors of $(2)$ to generate the class group. Note that one is the inverse of the other in the class group, so it suffices to find the order of one of the prime factors. Going through the computations shows that the fifth power is the first one that is principal, so the class group is cyclic with order $5$.

Comment: I didn't follow all the details of the computation, but your final answer is incorrect: the class group does not have order $2$.  (I agree with Will Jagy that the easiest way to compute the class number of an imaginary quadratic field is to enumerate all primitive reduced forms of the given discriminant.)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Thanks for the help. I am working to fix it.

Comment: Potato, better.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark It is fixed.

Comment: Potato, you might like this: if we have a (positive) prime $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ then the class number of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-p})$ must be odd. For example, I threw in $p=479$ below, the class number is 25 which is odd. Just one of those things.

Comment: @Potato: I was wondering how you got $\left(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2}\right)^2=(2,1+\sqrt{-47})$. When I multiply  the generators I get $\left(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2}\right)^2=\left(4,1+\sqrt{-47},\frac{-46+2\sqrt{-47}}{4}\right)=\left(4,1+\sqrt{-47},\frac{-23+\sqrt{-47}}{2}\right)$. But how does one reduce this further?

Comment: @Potato : And don't we have $2\cdot \frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2}=1+\sqrt{-47}$, i.e. $(2, 1+\sqrt{-47}) =(2)$ ?

Comment: @Thomas You may be right. The point is you just crank through it and find that the $5$th power of that ideal is principal. I remember making some corrections and might have missed an error or two.

Comment: @Thomas (Feel free to edit this answer if you can correct the computations. Let me know and I can make it community wiki.)

Comment: Your computations still look weird to me: especially your last equality: how can two ideals of two different norms be equal? That is, the norm of $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2})^5$ is $2^5$, but the norm of $(8)$ is $2^6$; how can they coincide? Also, how can $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2})^2=(2,1+\sqrt{-47})=(2)$, while the class group is of order $5$? Further, we have that $(\frac{9+\sqrt{-47}}{2})=I$ is of norm $2^5$, so $(2,\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2})^5$ is either $I$, or $\overline I$.

Comment: @awllower Yeah, things were initially messed up and got more messed up when I edited it. The point is this: We know we only need one prime factor of $(2)$ to generate the group, and all we need to do is find its order. So we can just multiply it by itself until we get a principal ideal.

Comment: Indeed. And sorry for replying late: I was trying to find the square of our ideal, by finding firstly an element of norm $4$... So stupid was I, in ending up with proving this obvious fact that it is impossible to do so. Haha:D So the only difficulty presented is to determine the powers of ideals, or to see when will it be principal. I think there is a certain similarity with the integral points on elliptic curves, where the Nagell-Lutz theorem is used likewise, but where the operations are easier. In any case, thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another attempt. In case I made any mistakes, let me know and I will either try and fix it, or delete my answer.

---

We have Minkowski bound $\frac{2 \sqrt{47}}{\pi}<\frac{2}{3}\cdot 7=\frac{14}{3}\approx 4.66$. So let us look at the primes $2$ and $3$:

$-47\equiv 1$ mod $8\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2$ is split, i.e. $(2)=P\overline P$ for some prime ideals $P,\overline P$.

NB: In fact we have $P=(2,\delta)$ and $\overline P=(2,\overline \delta)$ with $\delta=\frac{1+\sqrt{-47}}{2}$ and $\overline\delta=\frac{1-\sqrt{-47}}{2}$. But this is going to be irrelevant in the rest of the proof.

$-47\equiv 1$ mod $3\quad\Rightarrow\quad 3$ is split, i.e. $(3)=Q \overline Q$ for some prime ideals $Q,\overline Q$.

So the class group has at most 5 elements with representatives $(1),P,\overline P, Q, \overline Q$.

Note that $P$ is not principal, because $N(\frac{a+b\sqrt{-47}}{2})=\frac{a^2+47b^2}{4}=2$ does not have an integer solution (because $8$ is not a square). So $P$ does not have order $1$.

Suppose $P$ has order $2$. Then $P^2$ is a principal ideal with $N(P^2)=N(P)^2=2^2=4$. The only elements with norm $4$ are $\pm2$. But $P^2$ cannot be $(2)$, because $2$ is split.

Suppose $P$ has order $3$. Then $P^3$ is a principal ideal with $N(P^3)=N(P)^3=2^3=8$. But $N(\frac{a+b\sqrt{-47}}{2})=\frac{a^2+47b^2}{4}=8$ does not have an integer solution (because $32$ is not a square).

Suppose $P$ has order $4$. Then $P^4$ is a principal ideal with $N(P^4)=16$. The only elements with norm $16$ are $\pm4$. But $P^4$ cannot be $(4)$, because $(4)=(2)(2)=P\overline P P\overline P$ is the unique factorisation, and $P\ne \overline P$.

Suppose $P$ has order $5$. Then $P^5$ is a principal ideal with $N(P^5)=32$. And, indeed, the element $\frac{9+\sqrt{-47}}{2}$ has norm $32$.

So $P^5=(\frac{9+\sqrt{-47}}{2})$. Hence the class group is cyclic of order $5$.

Answer (score 3):

@potato, the chip way to do this is binary forms, certainly for negative discriminants. The result is five classes, an odd number which therefore guarantees that the principal genus ("squares") contains everything. Then I threw in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt {-479})$ because it goes slightly past the online table.

Note that the original computer they gave me was named phoebus, which refers to Apollo. When that broke, they tried to call it phoebusjunior but the spelling came out a bit off.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./classGroup
Absolute value of discriminant? 
47
  class  number  5

 all  
( 1, 1, 12)
( 2, -1, 6)
( 2, 1, 6)
( 3, -1, 4)
( 3, 1, 4)

 squares  
( 1, 1, 12)
( 2, -1, 6)
( 2, 1, 6)
( 3, -1, 4)
( 3, 1, 4)

Discriminant        -47     h :    5     Squares :    5
```

## ================

================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./classGroup
Absolute value of discriminant? 
479
  class  number  25

 all  
( 1, 1, 120)
( 2, -1, 60)
( 2, 1, 60)
( 3, -1, 40)
( 3, 1, 40)
( 4, -1, 30)
( 4, 1, 30)
( 5, -1, 24)
( 5, 1, 24)
( 6, -5, 21)
( 6, -1, 20)
( 6, 1, 20)
( 6, 5, 21)
( 7, -5, 18)
( 7, 5, 18)
( 8, -1, 15)
( 8, 1, 15)
( 9, -5, 14)
( 9, 5, 14)
( 10, -9, 14)
( 10, -1, 12)
( 10, 1, 12)
( 10, 9, 14)
( 11, -7, 12)
( 11, 7, 12)



Discriminant       -479     h :   25     Squares :   25     Fourths :   25
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ 
    jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

## ================

Comment: I'm really proud of changing "cheap" to "chip."