# Show that there are two ideal classes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Show that there are two ideal classes in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$.
I'm trying this problem with the Minkowski bound, please I need more help.
Thanks

Comment: What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Do you mean perhaps $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$?

Comment: Can you compute the Minkowski bound? The degree is $2$, with $2$ real embeddings and no complex embeddings.

Answer (score 2):

For real quadratic fields the Minkowski bound is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{d_k}$, where $d_k$ is the discriminant. For $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{10})$ we have $d_k=40$, hence the Minkowski bound is
about $3.16227766$. Hence every ideal class contains an integral ideal $I$ with norm $N(I)\le 3$. The class group is generated by prime ideals of norm less than or equal to $3$.
Now continue in the same way as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261828/class-group-of-mathbbq-sqrt-47), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/736214/class-group-of-ring-of-integers-of-mathbbq-sqrt-57) to see that the class group is cyclic of order $2$: the relevant factorizations are, with $\alpha=\sqrt{10}$,
$$
(2)=(2,\alpha)^2,\quad (3)=(3,\alpha+1)(3,\alpha+2)
$$
Both are not principal ideals, and the ideals on the right hand side are all equivalent. Now $P=(2,\alpha)$ has order $2$ and generates the class group.

Comment: why is the class group generated by prime ideals of norm less than or equal to  3?

Comment: @TiWen Because of the Minkowski bound.